# How to get current DB time from SQL Server using spring boot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I am using spring boot and SQL Server and getting unexpected end of subtree when I have the following code to get database time;

```
@Query("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
public Timestamp getTime();
```

`SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works when ran in SQL Server though.

and when I do the following, I get the timestamp but in a list, based on how many rows the table has:

```
@Query("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from MYTABLE")
public Timestamp getTime();
```

Comment: I removed your answer from your question, as you have correctly added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

ok I fixed it by doing:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nativeQuery = true)
public Timestamp getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java Persistence query language includes the built-in Datetime Functions, which may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause of a query. Such as:-

```
functions_returning_datetime:=
             CURRENT_DATE |
             CURRENT_TIME |
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This way you can get it by:-

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nativeQuery = true)
public Timestamp getTime();
```